# How To use NotificationChannel.SetSound under .NET MAUI

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, maui

I'm currently migration a project of mine from Xamarin.Forms to .NET MAUI. Thereby I'm struggling with migrating the creation of a NotificationChannel to MAUI incause of the incompatibility of Android.Net.Uri (needed for `Notification.SetSound(uri, attributes);`) and the System.Uri used in MAUI.

The NotificationChannel should have a specific notification sound with is located in the resources folder of the project.

Following code was used in Xamarin Forms:

```
var alarmAttributes = new AudioAttributes.Builder()
    .SetContentType(AudioContentType.Sonification)
    ?.SetUsage(AudioUsageKind.Alarm)
    ?.Build();

Android.Net.Uri alarmUri =
    Android.Net.Uri.Parse(
    $"{ContentResolver.SchemeAndroidResource}://{ApplicationContext?.PackageName}/{Resource.Raw.alarm}");

var alarmChannel = new NotificationChannel(id: Constants.AlarmNotificationChannel,
    name: "Alarm",
    importance: NotificationImportance.Max)
{
    Description = "Highest priority notifications appear in this channel"
};
alarmChannel.EnableLights(true);
alarmChannel.EnableVibration(true);
alarmChannel.SetBypassDnd(true);
alarmChannel.SetShowBadge(true);
alarmChannel.SetSound(alarmUri, alarmAttributes);
notificationChannels.Add(alarmChannel);
```

Is it possible to set the sound of the notificationchannel even under .NET MAUI? And how can I achieve this goal?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Your code runs in Xamarin.Android, the code that calls Android in maui has to try to use handler, the Handler system in MAUI is used to handle the implementation of native controls for different platforms, if you want to create controls, you only need to create handlers based on different platforms.

You can refer to this link: [Create a custom control using handlers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/handlers/create?view=net-maui-7.0).

There is a method on [GitHub:Plugin.LocalNotification](https://github.com/thudugala/Plugin.LocalNotification#pluginlocalnotification). The local notification plugin provides a way to show local notifications from .Net MAUI. One such feature is Custom Sounds, which is supported on the Maui platform.

Plugin.LocalNotification Available on NuGet: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Plugin.LocalNotification.

Hope it could help you.